# Generating checkboxes in a for loop & storing responses in list

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m having trouble with trying to generate checkboxes (using `tkinter`) in a for loop & store the responses as `0s&1`s/`true&false` in a list.

I currently have:

```
from tkinter import *
def createCheckButtons():
    dict_keys = ('a', 'b', 'c') # ...)
    numFields = len(dict_keys)

    master = Tk()
    cbVariables = {}
    cb = {}

    Label(master, text="Fields to Return").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    for x in range(numFields):
    cbVariables[x] = IntVar()
    cb[x] = Checkbutton(master, text=dict_keys[x], \
        variable=cbVariables[x]).grid(row=(x+1)%13,column=x//13,sticky=W)
    cbResponses = { }
    Button(master, text='Finished Selecting',command=vars_store(cbVariables,cb,numFields,\  
        cbResponses)).grid(row=(x+2),sticky=W, pady=4)

    mainloop() #master.mainloop()
    master.update()

def vars_store(cbVariables,cab,numFields, cbResponses)
    for x in range(numFields):
        cbResponses[x] = cb[x].get()

createCheckButtons()
```

Then, I want to reduce `dict_keys` to just the keys that were chosen with the Checkbuttons by doing something like:

```
reducedDict_Keys = { } 
For x in range(len(cbResponses)):
    if cbResponses[x]:
        reducedDict_Keys.append(dict_keys[x])
```

If there is a better way to do all this, please let me know!

Comment: Stop apologizing and tell us why those other solutions didn't work.

Comment: "If there is a better way to do all" - what's wrong now in this code? What are the problem(s) you see yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define that much `dict` to achieve what you want - one simple `list` will work fine. Just append your `IntVar` to the list during your for loop. You can also use `enumerate` to add a counter to an iterable, which in your case the `dict_keys`.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var_store = []
dict_keys = "abcdefgh" #string is an iterable too so you don't have to use a tuple of ("a","b","c"...)

def createCheckButtons(master):
    Label(master, text="Fields to Return").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    for num, x in enumerate(dict_keys):
        v = IntVar()
        Checkbutton(master, text=x, variable=v).grid(row=(num+1)%13,column=num//13,sticky=W)
        var_store.append(v)
    Button(master, text='Finished Selecting',command=vars_store).grid(sticky=W, pady=4)

def vars_store():
    result = [dict_keys[num] for num, i in enumerate(var_store) if i.get()]
    print (result)

createCheckButtons(root)

root.mainloop()
```